# Stimulsoft reports stuck in compiling/rendering report

Tags: apache-flex, stimulsoft

Demo Version
Stimulsoft Reports.Fx for FLEX
Version: 2013.3.1800 from 2013.12.02

Hi,

So im trying to make a simple report with date filter. I have two data in a single data band. First is the alert type and the other one is the modified date. When I open the preview mode it gets stuck on rendering report. It just keeps on loading. What I was expecting to happen in the preview mode is for it to let me enter the date for filter so that it wont fetch all 30,000 rows. Does this problem happen because its trying to get too many data or is it because there is a problem with the way I made the variable and the paramater for the filter? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Data Source in the Variables with Request From User paprameter?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is I have to much data. I was told by support that the app loads the data first then process it.

Comment: It's imossible to request parameter which use data source to get list of values and don't request all data from the Data Source.